# What battery has more capacity: Lithium Polymer or Lithium-ion battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lithium-polymer

In my project I need a battery with a cylinder of 10mm diameter and 35mm high. I thought only **Lithium Polymer** technology can create battery for this size. Now I discovery **Lithium-ion** can have the same size!

Both are very equal in voltage and capacity. But, the capacity is critical and if I can win 10 mAh for the same size, I will choice this technology.

So, is it easy to say what technology is better? Or it depend from manufacture? Or even: The differences are so small that it doesn't matter what I choice?

Comment: Lithium-Ion Polymer (Li-Po) tends to be more energy dense than Li-ion, but they're usually flat. If it's cylindrical, a Li-ion cell is probably a better pick - less dense, but you're using more of the space. Chemistry will have far less impact than which exact cell you use, though - batteries have come a long way even in the last five years.

Answer (score 4):

Both types of construction have similar characteristics in terms of degradation, charging behavior, and susceptibility to deep discharge problems, but:

- Li-Polymer have a slightly higher energy density because of the way in which the separator (salt bridge) is made. This comes at a 10-30% increase in cost, however.
- It's possible to make flexible batteries with Li-Polymer, and to make them thinner than Li-Ion.

Source: [http://www.allaboutsymbian.com...](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/features/item/15775_How_do_Lithium_batteries_work.php)

Comment: Note that [another site](http://www.androidauthority.com/lithium-ion-vs-lithium-polymer-whats-the-difference-27608/) states that the energy density of Li-Poly is *worse* than Li-Ion. I believe this information is out of date.

Comment: Just to give a feedback, price and weight is not a problem. I already see LiPol battery thinner as paper.

Comment: Can you give a number for this: slightly higher energy density? About 5%, maybe 10%?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to find any reliable information. Based on searches for recent information, I'd almost say it is negligible because some references indicate Li-Poly energy density is less while others indicate it is higher. I would guess 5% or less.